# Facebook Open Graph custom notifications available only to timeline users?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am developing a facebook application and would like to post custom notifications when certain events happen, but the Facebook tutorial only gives me the option to do this through their new Open Graph platform. Am I forced to use Open Graph and the new timeline feature or can I develop and post notifications for the older user profile model?

If development for older profiles is possible where can I look to find some good resources for it? All the tutorials on Facebook development and integration I'm finding are about their new Open Graph platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGraph is not mandatory you have other easy ways to reach users ;)

You can use the availability of posting on user's wall with Graph API
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

You also can use apprequests to send notifications directly to the user
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

Hope that helps